# Why do so many players immediately muck their cards when they think they won the hand?

Tags: live

When playing live, no matter cash games or tournaments, many players will muck their cards as soon as they think they won the pot. Of course most of the times they will be right and nothing happens but from time to time, they will overlook someone and muck a potentially winning hand.

From the first time i played live poker, I always waited for the dealer to push the chips to me, and only then give up my cards. I never understood why this isnt common practice.

Comment: waiting for the pot to give up cards is good paratice, I have had to play tug o war with dealers to makr sure I get the pot before giving up the cards, even been tempted to say aI will toss you my cards while you change this dollar chip to silver.

Comment: Because people are stupid, and would rather look cool than build good habits.

Answer (score 0):

my best guess is they want to get rid of the hand before someone asks to see it. for me I muck as soon as I figure out I lost. a few times I figured wrong and wish I took a little more time.

Answer (score -1):

There is no review when a hand makes the muck making any dispute more likely to go in thier favor

Comment: "brain"?! Must be a typo.

Comment: while I will admit to removing that last typo, I do not admit to making the original typo,  I no make typos..